# counting in for() count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = +1+thx)?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner when it comes to Javascript. With click, the number should increase by one.
I don't want to use tag IDs here, but as if made in class

```js
let clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.CounterTrigger'); // IE8
let count = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.CounterCount'));
let please = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.CounterPlease'));

let pleaseTxt = " Clicks! Please click!";
let i;
let thx = " Clicks! Thanks!";

please.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = pleaseTxt);

for (let i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++) {
  clicks[i].onclick = function () {

        let plus = +1;
        count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = +plus+thx);
        please.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = "");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="Counter">
  <button class="CounterTrigger">Button</button>
  <span class="CounterCount">1</span>
 <span class="CounterPlease"></span>
</div>
```

*What is wrong with these lines?*

```js
let plus = +1;
count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = +plus+thx);
```

**expected output before click**

> 1 Clicks! Please click!

**expected output after click**

> 2 Clicks! Thanks!!

**[Here the Example Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cemfirat/3pc6n4w7/latest/)**

Comment: Nothing is wrong with those lines - but you are really unclear in what you are trying to obtain. If you are interested in concatenating strings, you might want to try the `+=` operator rather than `=`. If you are trying to increase a count, your variables should probably be numeric and not strings. I suggest changing the question so it also provides an expected output.

Comment: Declare `plus` outside the `onclick` handler, so that it has a longer lifetime, and the handler will be a *closure which captures the variable* (the same way as it captures `count` and `please` arrays). And then use `++plus` or something inside the function, if you actually want to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve `number` value from your `innerHTML` with `i.innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0]`. Use `+` as `prefix` so it will convert it to `number`. Then add `1` and append `thx`.

All you need to update is one line as `count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = ((+i.innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0])+1) + thx);`.

You can check output below.

```js
let clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.CounterTrigger'); // IE8
let count = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.CounterCount'));
let please = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.CounterPlease'));

let pleaseTxt = " Clicks! Please click!";
let i;
let thx = " Clicks! Thanks!";

please.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = pleaseTxt);

for (let i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++) {
  clicks[i].onclick = function () {
        count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = ((+i.innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0])+1) + thx);
        please.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = "");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="Counter">
  <button class="CounterTrigger">Button</button>
  <span class="CounterCount">1</span>
    <span class="CounterPlease"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects regarding your question, first is the usage of the `+`:

The operator `+` can be a bit tricky in Javascript. At the same time it is used to concatenate strings, it is also use to [cast a variable to `Number`](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce). A good example is, if you have a string `"1"` and you apply the `+`, like `+"1"` this becomes `1`, a `Number` instead of its original `String` type. If you write `1 + "7"` this becomes `"17"`, as concatenation is applied instead.

Secondly is the problem you reported. If I got right, your idea is to increase the counter every time a button is clicked. However, if you check the code, every time a button is clicked, you have an `onclick` event which runs the anonymous function.

```js
clicks[i].onclick = function () {
    let plus = +1;
    count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = +plus+thx);
    please.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = "");
}
```

If you check carefully, on each click `plus` variable is always initiated with `1`. In order to increase this value on every click, you have to find a strategy to modify its value inside the click event instead of always declaring it.

The simplest way would be to declare the variable outside the function, e.g.:

```js
let plus = 1;
clicks[i].onclick = function () {
    count.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = plus + thx);
    please.forEach(i => i.innerHTML = "");
}
```

Depending on the problem you can also to track multiple `plus` values using an array or other data structure which fits best, but the idea behind is the same: you need to access to the current value, increment it and store it for the next usage.